# Wrong screen showing at start of app and launch screen or initial screen showing with delay

Tags: ios, launch

There is a weird issue with an iOS app. Initially there were no modifications on the Launch screen and the app started just with a white screen. Now the launch screen has been modified with black colour and an UIImageView in the centre, showing a png image. After that there is the Initial Screen that shows an animation for 1.5 seconds and then another screen is shown. Let's call it screen X. Before the modifications to the Launch screen Screen X was the initial screen of the application.

The issue is the following. On start of the application often instead of showing the Launch Screen first, Screen X is shown. Then after about a second the Initial Screen shows with the animation and then Screen X again. We tried deleting the app and the issue disappeared for a while, then reappeared. Is this some kind of caching? What could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

If the proper Launch Screen isn't being displayed, and you've already uninstalled the app, restarting the device usually fixes it.

Comment: We tried this also. It fixes the issue for a while and then it reappears. Is there a some kind of permanent solution to this

Comment: Every time it occurs, you restart the device. There is no permanent fix for this. It's likely a bug in Xcode/iOS.

Comment: @surToTheW, since this was the solution, please accept it.

Comment: Restarting the device removed the issue only temporarily and not always - this is why I didn't accept the answer. What I did was to make some changes in storyboard, remove the initial segues and add new ones with the same logic. Then I deleted the app and reinstalled it. This seems to have fixed the issue, but was waiting to check if it will not reappear.